# how to show highest value of mysql database in php

Tags: php, mysql

this is mysql table

```
---------------------------------------------
id | date       | name     |  amount 
---------------------------------------------
1  | 2013-01-31 | abcd     | 200.000 
2  | 2013-02-28 | apple    | 95.000
3  | 2013-03-31 | bannna   | 30.000
4  | 2013-04-30 | computer | 5.000
5  | 2013-05-31 | mobile   | 500.000 
6  | 2013-06-30 | mouse    | 2.000
7  | 2013-07-31 | led tv   | 25000.000
---------------------------------------------
```

how to find highest value amount of this table

i want result like this in php page
highest amount value 1st

```
Date       |  Name  | Amount
2013-07-31 | LED TV | 25000.000
2013-05-31 | Mobile | 500.000
2013-01-31 | Abcd   | 200.000
2013-02-28 | Apple  | 95.000
```

how can i do this please help me to fix this issue 
thanks

i am using this code but it is not showing my type of result.

```
<?php
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost"; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
 or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";

//select a database to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db("car",$dbhandle) 
  or die("Could not select examples");



//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mysql_query("SELECT MAX( amount ) AS amount FROM table5");

//fetch tha data from the database 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "Date:".$row{'date'}." Name:".$row{'name'}."Amount: ". //display the results
   $row{'amount'}."<br>";
}
//close the connection
mysql_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

Comment: is the amount an int or varchar?

Comment: Can you change your query SELECT MAX( amount ) AS amount FROM table5 order by amount desc or asc as per your need.

Comment: and you want just one highest record or the list sorted by highest amount first

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19130656/829533

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your attribute `amount` is a `varchar` (string) field you need to cast your attribute into `int` first

```
SELECT * FROM table5 ORDER BY CAST(amount as SIGNED INTEGER) DESC
```

If you only run following query

```
SELECT * FROM table5 ORDER BY amount DESC
```

It will sort the column as a string and the result will be

```
---------------------------------------------
id | date       | name     |  amount 
---------------------------------------------
2  | 2013-02-28 | apple    | 95.000
4  | 2013-04-30 | computer | 5.000
5  | 2013-05-31 | mobile   | 500.000
3  | 2013-03-31 | bannna   | 30.000
6  | 2013-06-30 | mouse    | 2.000
1  | 2013-01-31 | abcd     | 200.000 
7  | 2013-07-31 | led tv   | 25000.000
---------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query now, is

```
SELECT MAX( amount ) AS amount FROM table5
```

That query means: Get me the **one maximum value** of table5.

Instaed, that should be

```
SELECT * FROM table5 ORDER BY amount DESC
```

That query means: Get me **all values**, ordered from the highest to the lowest.

**UPDATE**:
The above query will work for `numeric` columns, not `varchars`, as the OP obviously wanted.

Comment: Actually his query should contain all the other columns he wants to display as per his code :)

Comment: Updated, as per Fluffeh's observation.

Comment: What is `normal data` and what is the data you expect to see like?

Answer (score 2):

Your below query returns only maximum value from amount field of `'table5'`,

```
SELECT MAX( amount ) AS amount FROM table5
```

But your need is different then it, instead of it you should write query like,

```
SELECT * FROM table5 ORDER BY amount DESC
```

Above query will return total number of rows from table5 in order of highest to lower value and that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table5 ORDER BY amount DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this query:

```
SELECT `date`, `name`, `amount` from `table` order by `amount` desc LIMIT 4
```

Because your query only shows the maximum one (only one record)

```
SELECT MAX( amount ) AS amount FROM table5
```

Answer (score 1):

`MAX` shows the Highest record in the column.It should be like this

```
SELECT * FROM your_table_name ORDER BY amount DESC
```